# bash: moving files with spaces

Tags: bash, files, mv

When I move a single file with spaces in the filename it works like this:

```
$ mv "file with spaces.txt" "new_place/file with spaces.txt"
```

Now I have a list of files which may contain spaces and I want to move them. For example:

```
$ echo "file with spaces.txt" > file_list.txt
$ for file in $(cat file_list.txt); do mv "$file" "new_place/$file"; done;

mv: cannot stat 'file': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'with': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'spaces.txt': No such file or directory
```

Why does the first example work, but the second one doese not? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

***Never, ever use `for foo in $(cat bar)`***. This is a classic mistake, commonly known as [bash pitfall number 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). You should instead use:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do mv -- "$file" "new_place/$file"; done < file_list.txt
```

When you run the `for` loop, bash will apply wordsplitting to what it reads, meaning that `a strange blue cloud` will be read as `a`, `strange`, `blue` and `cloud`:

```
$ cat files 
a strange blue cloud.txt
$ for file in $(cat files); do echo "$file"; done
a
strange
blue
cloud.txt
```

Compare to:

```
$ while IFS= read -r file; do echo "$file"; done < files 
a strange blue cloud.txt
```

Or even, if you insist on the [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html):

```
$ cat files | while IFS= read -r file; do echo "$file"; done
a strange blue cloud.txt
```

So, the `while` loop will read over its input and use the `read` to assign each line to a variable. The `IFS=` sets the input field separator to NULL<sup>*</sup>, and the `-r` option of `read` stops it from interpreting backslash escapes (so that `\t` is treated as slash + `t` and not as a tab). The `--` after the `mv` means "treat everything after the -- as an argument and not an option", which lets you deal with file names starting with `-` correctly.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>This isn't necessary here, strictly speaking, the only benefit in this scenario is that keeps `read` from removing any leading or trailing whitespace, but it is a good habit to get into for when you need to deal with filenames containing newline characters, or in general, when you need to be able to deal with arbitrary file names.</sub>

Comment: ok, I was only looking for ways to escape the "$file" part. did not expect the error somewhere else.

Comment: @MrJingles87 I know. This one gets *everyone* at some point. It is very unintuitive if you don't know about it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes indeed, good point. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: `IFS=` won't help with newlines in file names. The format of the file here simply doesn't allow filenames with newlines. `IFS=` is needed for file names beginning ending in space or tab (or whatever characters other than newline $IFS contained beforehand).

Comment: That _batch pitfall_ is more about trying to parse the output of `ls` or `find` with command substitutions when there are better, more reliable ways to do it. `$(cat file)` would be alright when done right. It's about as difficult to "do it right" with a while read loop as it is with that a for + $(...) one. See my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I did see your answer, but I admit I find it far more convoluted and complex than using a while loop. In any case, the pitfall page I linked to also explicitly mentions `IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat file); do . . .` which is why I linked to it. Perhaps a better link would be http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor .

Comment: But your `while` loop still has pitfalls. See in my answer how it has to be written to avoid them, which makes it not more legible than the `for` approach.

Answer (score 13):

That unquoted `$(cat file_list.txt)` in POSIX shells like `bash` in list context is the split+glob operator (`zsh` only does the *split* part as you'd expect).

It splits on characters of `$IFS` (by default, **SPC**, TAB  and NL) and does glob unless you turn off globbing altogether.

Here, you want to split on newline only and don't want the glob part, so it should be:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable globbing

for file in $(cat file_list.txt); do # split+glob
  mv -- "$file" "new_place/$file"
done
```

That also has the advantage (over a `while read` loop) to discard empty lines, preserve a trailing unterminated line, and preserve `mv`'s stdin (needed in case of prompts for instance).

It does have the disadvantage though that the full content of the file has to be stored in memory (several times with shells like `bash` and `zsh`).

With some shells (`ksh`, `zsh` and to a lesser extent `bash`), you can optimise it with `$(<file_list.txt)` instead of `$(cat file_list.txt)`.

To do the equivalent with a `while read` loop, you'd need:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r file || [ -n "$file" ]; do
  {
    [ -n "$file" ] || mv -- "$file" "new_place/$file"
  } 3<&-
done 3< file_list.txt
```

Or with `bash`:

```
readarray -t files < file_list.txt &&
for file in "${files[@]}"
  [ -n "$file" ] || mv -- "$file" "new_place/$file"
done
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
for file in ${(f)"$(<file_list.txt)"}
  mv -- "$file" "new_place/$file"
done
```

Or with GNU `mv` and `zsh`:

```
mv -t -- new_place ${(f)"$(<file_list.txt)"}
```

Or with GNU `mv` and GNU `xargs` and ksh/zsh/bash:

```
xargs -rd '\n' -a <(grep . file_list.txt) mv -t -- new_place
```

More reading about what it means to leave expansions unquoted at [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: I think you should acknowledge, though, that `$(cat file_list.txt)` reads the entire file into memory before iterating, whereas `while read ...` only reads one line at a time. This could be an issue for large files.

Comment: @chepner. Good point. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a script, you can use find..

```
 find -type f -iname \*.txt -print0 | xargs -IF -0 mv F /folder/to/destination/
```

for the case when the files are located in file then you can do the following::

```
cat file_with_spaces.txt | xargs -IF -0 mv F /folder/to/destination
```

the second not sure though..

Goodluck

Comment: If you're using `find`, you may as well use `find` for everything. Why bring `xargs` into it? `find -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec mv {} /folder/to/destination/`.

Comment: xargs simply manipulates the results of find here: -I assigns every results to a variable F while 0 and print0 simply guarantees files with spaces are not escaped. and -0 prevents xargs from escaping the results.
not sure how -exec behaves with spaces..

Comment: `-exec` behaves perfectly with arbitrary filenames (including those that contain spaces, newlines or any other weirdness). I know how `xargs` works, thanks :) I just don't see the point of calling a separate command when `find` can already do it for you. Nothing wrong with it, just inefficient.

Comment: @terdonyou are right.. -exec {} /path/destination works smoothly.. i prefer xargs because of more extra things i am able to do with it.

Comment: `xargs` also has the drawback of clobbering stdin (which `mv` needs for its prompts). Also a problem with @terdon's solution. With GNU `xargs` and shells with process substitution, can be alleviated with `xargs -0IF -a <(find...) mv F /dest`